# Convert string to multidimensional array to calculate date in php

Tags: php, arrays, date, multidimensional-array

I have a string as below

```
Mon[3,9] Tue[3,9] Wed[5,9] Thu[5,11] Fri[5,11] Sat[5,11] Sun[4,10]
```

I want to break this string to multidimensional array and store days like **Mon,Tue,Wed** as keys and the values inside square brackets as values for each day as below and access each day as smaller arrays

```
Array
(
    [Mon] => [3,9]
    [Tue] => [3,9]
    [Wed] => [5,9]
    [Thu] => [5,11]
    [Fri] => [5,11]
    [Sat] => [5,11]
    [Sun] => [4,10]
)
```

with this below code I was able to achieve it but the value such as `[3,9] or [5,11]` are being treated as strings

```
    $atd = $utd = "";
    $dod = "20-12-2020";
    $daysArray = "Mon[3,9] Tue[3,9] Wed[5,9] Thu[5,11] Fri[5,11] Sat[5,11] Sun[4,10]";
    $days = array('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun');
    preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $daysArray, $matches);
    $dayNum = $matches[0];
    $daysArray = array_combine($days , $dayNum);
    print_r($daysArray);
        
        $valArray = array();
        
        foreach($daysArray as $day=>$val){
            if($day == "Mon" || $day == "Tue"){
              $atd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+".$val[0]." days", $dod));
              $utd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+".$val[1]." days", $dod));
           }else if($day == "Sun"){
              $atd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+".$val[0]." days", $dod));
              $utd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+".$val[1]." days", $dod));
           }else if($day == "Wed"){
              $atd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+".$val[0]." days", $dod));
              $utd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+".$val[1]." days", $dod));
           }else{
              $atd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+".$val[0]." 5 days", $dod));
              $utd = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+".$val[1]." days", $dod));
             }
            }
        }
```

when I print `$valArray` it is a array like below which is very bad.

```
array(
   [0]=>[
   [1]=>4
   [2]=>,
   [3]=>1
   [4]=>0
   [5]=>]
);
```

Please help

Comment: Is this the actual code? You never set any value to $valArray

Comment: Also, `$days = array(Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun);` is invalid.

Comment: Sorry for that. The code inside foreach is the expectation. I either want to use $valArray or $val to get the numbers.

Comment: @0stone0 : update it. but it was not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the result you were asking for.

```
$str = 'Mon[3,9] Tue[3,9] Wed[5,9] Thu[5,11] Fri[5,11] Sat[5,11] Sun[4,10]';

$result = [];

$bits = explode(' ', $str); // explode on space between day names
foreach ( $bits as $bit) {
    $b = explode('[', $bit);    // $bit = Mon[3,9] 
    $b[1] = rtrim($b[1], ']');  // $b0 = Mon, B1 = 3,9] so trim off the last ]
    $result[$b[0]] = explode(',', $b[1]); // explode on , to get inner array
}
print_r($result);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [Mon] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 9
        )
    [Tue] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 9
        )
    [Wed] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 9
        )
    [Thu] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 11
        )
    [Fri] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 11
        )
    [Sat] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 11
        )
    [Sun] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 10
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$str = 'Mon[3,9] Tue[3,9] Wed[5,9] Thu[5,11] Fri[5,11] Sat[5,11] Sun[4,10]';
// convert main string to array by explode by empty space
$arr = explode(' ', $str);

$newArr = [];

foreach ($arr as $data) {
  // to get all b/n brackets best is to use regEx
  preg_match('#\[(.*?)\]#', $data, $match);
  // for key of new array use all befor 1st bracket
  // and for content explode data b/n brackets by ','
  $newArr[strtok($data, '[')] = explode(',', $match[1]);
}

var_dump($newArr);
```

Result:

```
array(7) {  ["Mon"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "9" } 
            ["Tue"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "9" }    
            ["Wed"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "9" } 
            ["Thu"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(2) "11" } 
            ["Fri"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(2) "11" } 
            ["Sat"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(2) "11" } 
            ["Sun"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "4" [1]=> string(2) "10" } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But this gives exactly the same result. [3,9] are returned as strings

Comment: oooh didn't read the issue ... Ill fix it now

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion:

```php
$days = "Mon[3,9] Tue[3,9] Wed[5,9] Thu[5,11] Fri[5,11] Sat[5,11] Sun[4,10]";
$individualDays = explode(' ', $days);
$result = [];
foreach ($individualDays as $individualDay) {
    $dates = preg_match_all('/\d+/', $individualDay, $matches);
    $result[substr($individualDay, 0, 3)] = $matches[0];
}
```

How it works:

- All your values are separated by a space, so we first explode by it to get an array of individual strings (`Mon[3,9]`, `Tue[3,9]` and so on) we can iterate.
- The first three characters of each of those strings are the day designation and we use that as the key for our new resulting array (utilizing `substr`).
- We match all numbers in `preg_match_all` and assign the array of matches to that key.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But again here this substr($individualDay, 0, 3) could lead to a problem if the digits of the numbers inside the brackets increases.

Comment: What do you mean if the number of digits increases? This only extracts the first three characters, which are `Mon`, `Tue`, etc. It does not affect the number of dates that follows. You can add any number of dates and test, you'll see it delivers the expected results.

Comment: @hemanthkumar Here's a [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/coh9X) with a variable number of dates assigned to every day.

Comment: Oops Sorry.! Extracting days was not an issue. The issue was to assign each day with respective sub values in the square brackets Mon =>(3,9) Wed=>(5,9). My code was working fine till extracting the days. then it was not considering [3,9] or [5,11] as array. Your answer is correct but it is a part of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use a pattern to match the individual parts using capturing groups and [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

Pass an array by reference to the callback to set the group 1 value as the key, and an array with the values of group 2 and group 3.

```
([a-z]+)\[(\d+),(\d+)]
```

**Explanation**

- `([a-z]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ a char a-z
- `\[` Match `[`
- `(\d+),(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in capture group 2 and group 3 and match a `,` in between
- `]` Match closing `]`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mMOZ3O/1) and a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/c8h01)

Example using a case insensitive match `/i`

```
$pattern = '/([a-z]+)\[(\d+),(\d+)]/i';
$str = 'Mon[3,9] Tue[3,9] Wed[5,9] Thu[5,11] Fri[5,11] Sat[5,11] Sun[4,10]';
$result = [];

preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern,
    function ($m) use (&$result) {
        $result[$m[1]] = [$m[2], $m[3]];
    },
    $str
);

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [Mon] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 9
        )

    [Tue] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 9
        )

    [Wed] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 9
        )

    [Thu] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 11
        )

    [Fri] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 11
        )

    [Sat] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 11
        )

    [Sun] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 10
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution converts the string to a JSON string by replacing characters. To create the desired array, only one json_decode() is necessary.

```
$input = 'Mon[3,9] Tue[3,9] Wed[5,9] Thu[5,11] Fri[5,11] Sat[5,11] Sun[4,10]';

$strJson = '{"'.strtr($input,[" " => ',"','[' => '":['])."}";
$array = json_decode($strJson, true);

//test output
echo "<pre>".var_export($array, true)."/<pre>";
```